# Cannot find symbol even though class (Font) & method (font) are declared?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing my codes and couldn't compile even though the class (Font) is already imported via `import javafx.scene.text.*;` and I know that method `font` is included within Font.

Here's my code:

```
package helloworld;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("PDF Export");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        Text scenetitle = new Text("PDF Password");
        scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma",FontWeight.NORMAL,20));
        grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);
...

}
```

And when I compile, here's the error I got

```
PS D:\Documents\javafx\helloworld> javac HelloWorld.java
HelloWorld.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
                scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma",FontWeight.NORMAL,20));
                                       ^
  symbol:   method font(String,FontWeight,int)
  location: class Font
1 error
```

Would anyone kindly tell me what I'm missing? Because I can't seem to figure out what I might have done wrong.

Comment: I pasted your code (without the `...`) into my IDE and it compiled without error. Check you don't accidentally have the `java.awt.Font` imported as well as the `javafx.scene.text.*` import.

Comment: @James_D: Yes, I've looked back into my import and it seems that the compiler have been confused with the libraries I imported. Thanks again for reminding me of the mixing up...

Answer (score 1):

I find that a lot with JavaFX I have to clean my project after any changes to the things related to JavaFX.

(I run NetBeans but the error could be in other IDEs as well).